# postgres 9.6 - jsonb & indexing - poor performances

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb, database-indexes, postgres-9.6

On a table (used by a django model) I'm using jsonb column `data` to store arbitrary data fetched from a webservice:

```
abs=# \d data_importer_rawdata;
                                        Table "public.data_importer_rawdata"
    Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------
id              | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('data_importer_rawdata_id_seq'::regclass)
created         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
modified        | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
entity_id       | character varying(50)[]  |           | not null |
entity_id_key   | character varying(50)[]  |           | not null |
service         | character varying(100)   |           | not null |
data            | jsonb                    |           | not null |
data_hash       | bigint                   |           | not null |
content_type_id | integer                  |           | not null |
last_update     | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
Indexes:
    "data_importer_rawdata_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "data_importer_rawdata_entity_id_service_conten_5fcc60bd_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (entity_id, service, content_type_id)
    "data_importer_rawdata_content_type_id_63138c35" btree (content_type_id)
    "rawdata_data_idx" gin (data jsonb_path_ops)
    "rawdata_entity_id_idx" btree (entity_id)
    "rawdata_entity_id_key_idx" btree (entity_id_key)
    "rawdata_service_idx" btree (service)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "data_importer_rawdat_content_type_id_63138c35_fk_django_co" FOREIGN KEY (content_type_id) REFERENCES django_content_type(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

records are > 1M.

However, despite various indexing strategies (followed [this blog post](http://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/?ckattempt=1)), performance is still poor:

```
abs=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
         "data_importer_rawdata"."id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."created",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."modified",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id_key",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."service",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."content_type_id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."data",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."data_hash",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."last_update"
FROM "data_importer_rawdata"
WHERE ("data_importer_rawdata"."data" -> 'object_id')
      = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"';
                                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on data_importer_rawdata  (cost=0.00..142508.65 rows=5155 width=856) (actual time=933.902..8240.465 rows=2 loops=1)
Filter: ((data -> 'object_id'::text) = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"'::jsonb)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1030908
Planning time: 0.158 ms
Execution time: 8240.493 ms
```

I tried to drop `"rawdata_data_idx"` and use a `BTree` index on a single jsonb key `object_id`, but performances are pretty much the same:

```
abs=# drop index "rawdata_data_idx";
abs=# CREATE INDEX "rawdata_data_object_ididx"
         ON "data_importer_rawdata" USING BTREE ((data->>'object_id'));

abs=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
         "data_importer_rawdata"."id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."created",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."modified",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."entity_id_key",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."service",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."content_type_id",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."data",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."data_hash",
         "data_importer_rawdata"."last_update"
FROM "data_importer_rawdata"
WHERE ("data_importer_rawdata"."data" -> 'object_id')
      = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"';
                                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on data_importer_rawdata  (cost=0.00..142508.65 rows=5155 width=856) (actual time=951.522..8318.851 rows=2 loops=1)
Filter: ((data -> 'object_id'::text) = '"b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1"'::jsonb)
Rows Removed by Filter: 1030908
Planning time: 0.311 ms
Execution time: 8318.878 ms
```

Any suggestion about that? Not sure that this is the average performance for this kind of task.

Comment: After adding/changing indexes, you should run `ANALYZE` on the table to refresh the statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Your query execution is slow because the index cannot be used.

To use the index, the expression in the condition must be the same as in the definition of the index, i.e.

```
WHERE "data_importer_rawdata"."data" ->> 'object_id'
      = 'b8a096da-ff83-47dc-8d22-289ddb46b1c1'
```